# What is the purpose of everything to the right of the proton exchange membrane in a microbial fuel cell?

Tags: solar-cell, multimeter, electricity

A standard microbial fuel cell looks like:
[image: this]
And my question is, why is the cathode and bascially the entire right chamber necessary for electricity production if the load (or the multimeter) can be attached to that area that says "electricity" and can produce electricity?

Would there be an actual problem if one were to leave the hydrogen cations just floating in the anionic chamber?

Comment: In order for electricity to be produced, a voltage must be produced. The positive side is the anode, and the negative the cathode. The figure simply shows the processes which occur in a microbial fuel cell. If there were no anode/cathode production, there would be no electricity.

Comment: Yes there would be a problem : it would build up a positive charge, which would attract the electrons and stop them leaving the anode, so it would simply stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just left the H<sup>+</sup> ions floating around, then the area around the anode would be positively charged.  Eventually the potential will get high enough so that it prevents new positive charges coming off the anode.

This is actually what happens when you leave a batter open circuit, and why that doesn't use up the battery.  The reaction quickly reaches a equalibrium where the "waste" of the reaction builds up so that more can't be produced.  The reaction stops and the battery is not depeleted.

When the charges are given a path to flow, they get swept away from the anode as they are produced.  The reaction now acts as a pump.  We can harness the energy in the charges being at a elevated voltage.  The faster the charges are removed, the faster more can be made, and the faster the chemicals in the battery get used up.

Comment: Alright, so from this would I be correct to say that the reason that there is a current at all is because the electrons are attracted to the hydrogen protons in the cationic chamber? Or is the metal/substance that the cathode is made of play an actual role in the electron transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you don't put electrons back to tank, soon a charge will build up and stop the current. It's like in any battery- electrons are "separated" from their ions and must come back from other side to keep total charge at zero. Otherwise reverse voltage would build up. It absolutely is not related to specific battery technology.